# Can one God be decorated to other look like other God?

Tags: temple

Each god will have a different name, form, mantra and qualities. During festive seasons or other occasions we see one god will be decorated to look like different god. Each Murthi will be installed on a very particular yantra, by performing particular rituals, so how can we do alankara to one god to look like another god or another avatar?

Its prominent practice on Dasara, Sri Krishna's & Sri Rama's birthday. On Rama's birthday will visiting Rama's temple and visiting Krishna's temple (krishna murthi decorated with Rama's attire) bless us with same result?

Answer (score 1):

If you copy someone and do not have your own uniqueness, you are not creative by nature. Each GOD has their unique quality. Now to copy Rama's Alankara to Gansha, does not bring any significance of doing so. By human nature you may have joy, fun or something you will feel you have done something strange, but It does not bring any meaning at all.

Blessing is beyond clothes, alankara and appearance. Blessing has nothing to do with alankaras. **Blessing or worshiping is a feeling of heart**, do you believe that they have anything to do with changing GOD's appearance? Blessings are just blessings, there are not any types in it.

Rama and Krishna is the same supreme being Lord Vishnu in Hinduism, so there is no difference that you see Rama in Krishna or you see Krishna in Rama. In Hinduism all GODs are manifestation of same supreme GOD. GODs always bless with bliss, love, purity based on our eligibility. So Krishna or Rama are just 2 notice boards for 2 avataras, after all they all are same GOD Lord Maha Vishnu.

Hinduism is a religion who teach you towards "
एकता(Unity)" from "भिन्नता(Separation)". That is true religion. True religion can not separate GODs.